# What are the value type of letters or symbols that we type and display on screen?

Tags: string, image, text, uitextfield, cpu-word

I am new to coding. I am developing a text editing app.

As curious, I am wondering what is letter displayed on screen? For example, we we type "a", "a" will pop up on the screen. So what is value type of that "a". Is it a small image or something else?

If it is a image, the image has to have a see-through "background" (I dont't know what it is called correctly). How can I create a image like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your computer characters are stored as their ASCII values. So "a" is actually 097, which is stored in memory as "01100001".

What you see on screen has nothing to do with how it is stored. How it is displayed depends on your output device. I can make a device which upon receiving "a" triggers my room's lamp.

A monitor makes the shape of "a" upon receiving "a". What about different fonts? Fonts aren't intrinsic to letters. They're a characteristic of either the display device or the word processor. A word processor upon receiving "a" checks what font the program is set to, and tells the display device to make a corresponding shape of "a" somewhere on the screen.

Comment: Not many computers use the ASCII character set. In the PC world, there is a dotmatrix font table for [OEM437](https://www.dafont.com/perfect-dos-vga-437.font) characters at address B000:0000. Today, fonts are stored in font files and usually are described by vectors (e.g., splines) and indexed by [Unicode](http://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) codepoints, such as .